# add class don't work with my ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I am having two different scripts. both of the scripts work alone, but not when I add both scripts to the page.

I switch pages by using AJAX, but then I also want jQuery to highlight the link I click on so that it can show the "active" page.

My HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul id="navUl">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">test1</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">test2</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="result">
    <div id="content">
        <p>random content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My AJAX/jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($){
        $('nav a').click(function(){

            var href = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';

            $('#result').load(href);

            return false;
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

This works perfectly, but when I add this to the script, that highlights the selected page, then my AJAX does not work anymore.

```
$(function() {
    $( '#navUl li' ).on( 'click', function() {
        $( this ).parent().find( 'li.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
        $( this ).addClass( 'active' );
    });
});
```

Comment: There are no `span`s in your code. The code inside $(function(){}); is run when the body is ready, meaning if an element is not found (in this case, `#navUl span`, no code will be called for it. You should check the console to see if there's an error.

Comment: There is most likely an error in your code, then. I'm assuming you run the second JS block you posted before the one with your AJAX in it. When a script errors, nothing after it is executed unless the exception is caught. Check the console.

Comment: @Lemmmy oops, I apologize. that's because I had tried wrapping a span around the li to see if that would work, because then the same tags would not be used in both functions. But it did not work... And I just forgot to edit that back.

Comment: @Lemmmy that cannot be the case :/ because I have tried running it with the scripts in different ways, and nothing work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return false from `nav a` click event, this will prevent the event bubbling up to the `li`.

Change to:

```
(function($){
        $('nav a').click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

            var href = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';

            $('#result').load(href);
        });
    })(jQuery);
```